# Post Variable New Line

Tags: php, mysql, post

How would I get this syntax? Really having issues...

```
for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ )
{
    $typeofunit = $_POST['typeofunit'.$i];}
    $sql="INSERT INTO equips (typeofunit)
    VALUES
    ('$_POST[typeofunit]')"; **??** ('$_POST[$typeofunit]')"; **???**
}
```

Comment: the goal of your code ?

Comment: I have a table uses a script to create a new line/table. Need to post to mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `INSERT` statement outside of your loop because you only need it once. Then append to it during each loop iteration. Lastly, remove the last comma from the query which would cause a syntax error.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO equips (typeofunit) VALUES";
for( $i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++ )
{
    $typeofunit = $_POST['typeofunit'.$i];}
    $sql .= "('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['typeofunit'.$i]) . "'),"; 
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ',');
```

You will notice I also escaped the `POST` variable. You *must* do this to prevent SQL injections. In an ideal world, you would switch to prepared statements which are even safer.